# Trying to convert numpy array with ctypes to C gives Segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

So my problem is that i trying to convert image data to continuous array to pass it to C library, but for some reason numpy gives segmentation fault on too long array. Look at the example

```
data =  np.ascontiguousarray(np.array([1]*10000, dtype=np.float32)/255).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
print data.contents.value # ok

data =  np.ascontiguousarray(np.array([1]*1000000, dtype=np.float32)/255).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
print data.contents.value #giving segmentation fault
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these libraries, but it's possible you've found a bug in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because with your one-line construction, the numpy array object has no references held to it, so it is being garbage collected, then you are trying to dereference a dangling pointer. I tried your code and avoided the segfault by breaking the line into two - one line to create the numpy array, then a second one to obtain the pointer into the underlying storage:

```
x = np.ascontiguousarray(np.array([1]*10000000, dtype=np.float32)/255)
data = x.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
print data.contents.value # no more segmentation fault
```

I guess the larger memory block is more aggressively collected, hence the difference in behaviour depending on size. I also had to increase the memory size to get a segfault on my machine.